# what is wrong with following right triangle's hypotenuse's square reasoning

Tags: triangles

[In the image given in the link, the square of the hypotenuse is 2ab. But it can't be true. I can't be true. I can't seem to find the reason. any help would be appreciated.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taUqV.png)

Comment: Is that figure meant to be a square?  If so...the diagonals of a square are equal so we'd need $a=b$.  If it's not meant to be a square then the area of the figure is not $c^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you talk about hypotenuse, it means that the diagonals of the quadrilateral are perpendicular. Using $$c^2=a^2+b^2$$ and $$c^2=2ab$$ you get $$a^2+b^2-2ab=0$$ or $$(a-b)^2=0$$This is valid for $a=b$

Comment: i was trying to prove pythagoras theorem